# kill - does it kill the process right away?

Tags: c, process, freebsd, kill, defunct

what does `kill` exactly do?

I have a parent process which is creating 100 (as an example) child processes one after another. At the end of any child's job, I kill the child with `kill(pid_of_child, SIGKILL)` and I cannot see that in `ps` output. But if something goes wrong with the parent process and I exit from the parent process with `exit(1)` (at this point only 1 child is there - I can check tht in `ps`), at that point I see a lot of `<defunct>` processes whose `ppid` is `pid` of parent process.

How is that possible? did `kill` not kill the child processes entirely?

Comment: @ChrisO: The kernel does not reap zombies, ever.  Only `init` reaps zombies, and only zombies that are its own children.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I have  a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481803/can-a-child-process-go-defunct-without-its-parent-process-dying

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`kill` doesn't kill *anything*. It sends signals to the target process. `SIGKILL` is just a signal. Now, the standard action for `SIGKILL` -- the only action, actually, since `SIGKILL` can't be handled or ignored by a process --  is to exit, that's true.

The "<defunct>" process is a child that hasn't been *reaped*, meaning that the parent hasn't called `wait()` to retrieve the exit status of the child. Until the parent calls `wait()`, the defunct (or "zombie") process will hang around.

Comment: "Now, the standard action for SIGKILL is to exit, that's true." - It's worth mentioning that there cannot be a "nonstandard action" for it, since `SIGKILL` cannot be caught or ignored (contrast e.g. with `SIGTERM`, which is often caught to perform a clean process termination).

Comment: Thanks Ernest and @Dietrich Epp: So, when `kill` is called for a pid, that pid cannot be seen in the `ps` output but that does not mean, its all done and that pid has been given back to process table. - is that a correct assumption? So, parent should `wait` right after `kill`ing the child to avoid `<defunct>`s?

Comment: Whether you'll see the child in your `ps` output depends on the options you give to `ps` (and the specific implementation of that tool I suppose). But yes, calling `wait()` when a child is exiting is a good idea. You normally get a `SIGCHLD` signal when a child exits; this is a fine time to call `wait()`, in the handler for that signal.

Comment: So, I can call wait() right after kill(), something like this: kill (pid_of_child, SIGKILL); waitpid(pid_of_child, &status, WNOHANG);  - would that be a correct way?

Comment: Yes (if you're killing your own child process.) The parent process has to be the one to call `wait()`.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever a process ends, no matter how it ends (`kill` or otherwise), it will stay in the kernel's process table until its parent process retrieves its exit status (with `wait` and friends).  Leaving it in the process table avoids a number of nasty race conditions.

If your parent process has exited, the children should get reassigned to `init`, which periodically reaps its children.

Comment: So, if I want to avoid <defunct>/Zombies, what should parent do? In my case, in error condition, I am doing `exit()` from the parent. Should I do anything (clean up) before exiting?

Comment: long time ago. but answer is, call signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) before forking your childs and they will get repeaded nearly immediately

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SIGKILL terminates the process, but in any case (either normal exit or terminated), processes have an exit status, which needs to be kept around for potential readers - as such an entry in the process table may remain until this is done. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process .